# Google Maps API indoor buildings list

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-indoor-maps

I know the question may be a bit off-topic on SO and understand the risk being downvoted, however lots of research have given me no results.
Basically the question is: **"Can i get the list of buildings having indoor maps for specific filters, particularly location/radius/coordinates?"**
I mean, there definitely should be REST API for this task, however i couldn't find it out.

**EDIT1**
https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827 has the list of indoors, however it's not exactly what i need. Exploring `GMSIndoorBuilding` class (iOS SDK) gives info like `indoorID`, `bounds`, `center` private properties... google has the way to obtain that info. Does anybody know any public APIs for this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a almost full list of the indoor maps with countries from Google, but i have no idea how often are they updating this website. [https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827) Indoor maps are still not available for all countries in the world.

Comment: Yeah, saw it.. however it's not a good to parse HTML for getting indoor list + i'm interested in additional info like location etc. Because exploring GMSIndoorBuilding class (iOS SDK) gives info like indoorID, bounds, center... google has the way to obtain it.